# OData query for all rows from the last 10 minutes

Tags: azure, odata, azure-storage

I need to filter rows from an Azure Table Store that are less than 10 minutes old. I'm using a Azure Function App integration to query the table, so a coded solution is not viable in this case.

I'm aware of the `datetime` type, but for this I have to specify an explicit datetime, for example -

```
Timestamp gt datetime'2018-07-10T12:00:00.1234567Z'
```

However, this is insufficient as I need the query to run on a timer every 10 minutes.

According to the OData docs, there are built in functions such as `totaloffsetminutes()` and `now()`, but using these causes the function to fail.

> [Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.FailedEventsCount. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Is there a way to query a Table Store dynamically in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was easier than expected.

I added the following query filter to the Azure Table Store input integration -

```
Timestamp gt datetime'{afterDateTime}'
```

In conjunction with a parameter in the Function trigger route, and Bob's your uncle -

```
FailedEventsCount/after/{afterDateTime}
```

Appreciate for other use cases it may not be viable to pass in the datatime, but for me that is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: It's not recommended to query Azure Table with non-key columns in filter only, please at least include Partition Key filter, or it will result in a full table scan. For more details about how to design a table with performant query, please check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide

Comment: I am filtering on PartitionKey. The integration offers options to filter on that and/or RowKey, as well as an additional filter query.